# To hide the addressbar,standardbar in asp.net from codebehind

Tags: asp.net

in my application am loading my firstpage from startpage in codebehind by Response.redirect and here i need to hide the addressbar and standardbar of that firstpage while loading .can anyone help for this.Note:the firstpage is masterpage content.

Answer (score 0):

These are things that are on the browser and as such can't be directly controlled by server side code (i.e. code behind).

You will need to emit some javascript to open the window with your specification. If the window you are redirecting in, already has the address bar etc..., there isn't much you can do to change the appearance.

Here is a good [overview](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml) of how `window.open` works in javascript.